# Build failed with an exception? Android

Tags: android, gradle, exception, build.gradle

The project is running fine when i remove the `implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.3.6'` from the gradle

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not find com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.3.6.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s

[image: build.gradle file]

[image: Logcat Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please verify the version of Lottie.

Latest version you can find here: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'
```